# Run .each() based on elements within specific tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a layout with something to this effect:

```
<div id="issueWidgets">
   <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet" id="boxIssues">
            <div class="portlet-header">Some Title</div>
                   <div class="portlet-content">Some content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
         <div class="portlet" id="boxStats">
            <div class="portlet-header">Some Stats Title</div>
                   <div class="portlet-content">Some Stats content</div>
         </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="projectWidgets">
   <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet" id="boxProjects">
            <div class="portlet-header">Some Title</div>
                   <div class="portlet-content">Some content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="userWidgets">
   <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet" id="boxUsers">
            <div class="portlet-header">Some Title</div>
                   <div class="portlet-content">Some content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <div class="portlet" id="boxUsers2">
            <div class="portlet-header">Some Title</div>
                   <div class="portlet-content">Some content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And on and on...Each main div serves as a jquery ui tab.
So basically I've got tabs (as divs with the following IDs: issueWidgets, projectWidgets, and userWidgets).  These divs contain some portlet divs (these are just divs that act as widgets within each column (div class=column).

I've got code that looks for each class with name column to create some cookie information like so:

```
  // function that writes the list order to a cookie 
        function saveOrder() { 
            $(".column").each(function(index, value){ 
                var colid = value.id; 
                var cookieName = "cookie-" + colid; 
                // Get the order for this column. 
                var order = $('#' + colid).sortable("toArray"); 
                // For each portlet in the column 
                for ( var i = 0, n = order.length; i < n; i++ ) { 
                    // Determine if it is 'opened' or 'closed' 
                    var v = $('#' + order[i]).find('.portlet-content').is(':visible'); 
                    // Modify the array we're saving to indicate what's open and 
                    //  what's not. 
                    order[i] = order[i] + ":" + v; 
                } 
                $.cookie(cookieName, order, { path: "/", expiry: new Date(2016, 1, 1)}); 
            }); 
        }
```

The issue I am having is this runs for every element with class name column.  So basically it goes out to issueWidgets and finds each column, and goes to projectWidget and finds any element with class=column, and finally to userWidgets and also finds any element with class=column and runs the above code.

I want to limit it to run based on the its parent widget div.  So for instance I'd want it to run only on issueWidgets when I am looking at the issueWidgets tab.  Remember these are actually tabs (jquery ui).  If I'm in the projectWidgets tab I'd want to find all elements with class=column but ONLY on the projectWidgets tab not all the other tabs...etc etc.

So basically my function should take in the tab either issueWidgets, projectWidgets, userWidgets and work .each only located within those tabs.

### edit

I'm not sure how to modify this to use find(), since the original code within document ready looks like this:

```
 $(".column").sortable({
                connectWith: ".column",
                handle: ".portlet-header",
                cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
                placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all",
                stop: function () { saveOrder(); }
            });

            $(".portlet")
                .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
                .find(".portlet-header")
                .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
                .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>")
                .end()
                .find(".portlet-content");

            restoreOrder();

            $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").hover(
                function () { $(this).addClass("ui-icon-hover"); },
                function () { $(this).removeClass('ui-icon-hover'); }
            );

            $(".portlet-toggle").click(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
                icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
                saveOrder();
            });
```

Comment: Just use `.find()` starting from the DOM element corresponding to the tab.

Comment: Pointy that is my question, see my edit, I don't know how I can use find() in this case to call saveOrder and restoreOrder.  My issue is when I use jquery ui tabs feature the items not on the active tab are marked automatically closed because they are not  ":visible"...that is my issue.  So that is why I want to limit to the specific tab that I am on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the parent of that element and compare.

```
$(".column").each(function(index, value){ 

   // If isn't the parent you're looking for.. 
   if($(this).parent().attr('id') != 'projectWidgets'){
      continue;
   }

   // the rest of your code
}
```

**EDIT**: According to the answers below, new code:

I'm assuming that the code you post (`var selectedTabIndex = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');`) gives the HTML content, am I right?

If so, use instead something like this:

```
$tabSelected = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
```

and all you have to do is `find` the `.column`.

```
$tabSelected.find('.column').each(function(index, value){

});
```

**EDIT 2**: According to the jQuery Tab documentation:

> Since the activate event is only fired on tab activation, it is not
>   fired for the initial tab when the tabs widget is created. If you need
>   a hook for widget creation use the create event.

So, take care, you might need `create` event also. The below code should do the trick.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  activate: function(event, ui){

    $(this).find('.column').each(function(i, value){

    });
  }
});
```

Comment: i'd rather not really hardcode the widget names as these can change and there are many...Hence my question of how to capture that div and pass into the function?

Comment: Then you need to find out what tab is currently active and apply the same condition. When a tab is active, usually it add's the following class to it `active`, check if it's your case.

Comment: Hmm...but why cant I simply pass something else to saveOrder() and apply it before the `$(.column).each()` something that says something to the effect of `$(someParentWidget).(.column).each()` meaning instead of grabbing every element with id column, grab only those within someParentWidget?

Comment: Yes you can, but again we need to know which tab is currently active. If the widget you're using (which I doubt) isn't placing a class named `active` or something similiar when tabs are changed, then you'll have to code it.

Comment: I can get the active tab with this: `var selectedTabIndex = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');` but how can I change the saveOrder() method to .each elements with class name = column BUT only for that active tab?  Meaning I want to run $(".column").each() but only for elements within that active tab...

Comment: What is the tab component you're using? - Edit: btw, returning the ID solves the problem with my first solution.

Comment: What am I looking to bring back, if I do this: $("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id"); I get the ID, of the tab for instance issueWidget, can I then apply find to that or do I need to get the entire HTML element?  Im using this http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Right but your first solution would have to traverse ALL elements with class column, can I restrict it only to the selected tab?

Comment: Yes, next time tell us the plugin you're using, is more easy. Take a look at their documentation and my edited post.

Comment: I want to find within my saveOrder function and not within the tabs declaration...so cant I within that original function do something like that where I pass in the tab and then perform the .each?

Comment: Well, with that we'll need again to back to my first solution, but this time you need to pass the ID through the `saveOrder` function. Something like `saveOrder(selectedIndex)`. After that, you'll use it this way `$('#' + selectedIndex).find('.column')...`

Comment: Yep I am understanding it now, is it better or faster that way or is it the same as something like this: `var activeTab = $("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id");
            $('.column').each(function (index, value) {
                if ($(this).parent().attr('id') == activeTab) {...`

Comment: The way you're trying to implement is more effective and correct. Otherwise if you have tons of `.column` classes it will loop through them unnecessarily.